How to query post table with referenced user and storage
I am new with Supabase
I have post table like this :
post{
id,
title,
user_id,
avatar_id
}

as you can guess , user_id and photo_id are foreign keys and they are related to user table and avatar storage
now I wanna to query post with populated foreign key
supabase.from('post').select('title,avatar_id(*),user_id(*)')

but I face error like this
Searched for a foreign key relationship between 'post' and 'user_id' in the schema 'public', but no matches were found

whats the problem ?

Querying across multiple schemas don't work great in Supabase right now. If you want to reference the storage objects related to your data, just store the storage path as one of the columns on the posts table.
